# How to capture the value change of numericUpDown ctrl real-time in .NET?

Tags: .net

I have implement the **ValueChanged** event, but I found it will be triggered only after change the focus from numericUpDown to other control or by clicking the up/down arrow.

Inputting the value in the control will not trigger **ValueChanged** event.

What I did now is adding an **KeyDown** event and judge if the input value is numeric (can not include SHIFT/CTRL/ALT key); but there is another case need to be involved: the user can paste value into the numericUpDown ctrl

***What I need is :***

1. When I was typing numeric value (only numeric) in the numericUpDown ctrl, it will known the content has been changed;
2. When pasted a numeric value into the ctrl, it also kowns the content changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered your related other question about numeric updown control:

[how to hold the invalid value for NumericUpDown after it loses focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316048/how-to-hold-the-invalid-value-for-numericupdown-after-it-loses-focus/2316219#2316219)

You can use the same technique I described there to handle the TextChanged event of the embedded textbox.

Best regards...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest subclassing the NumericUpDown and overriding the OnTextBoxTextChanged method to raise the ValueChanged event.

You would also need to consider what represents a change, you may get unexpected results if you raise the Valuechanged when the user has typed a single digit and then a second digit. Or a non-numeric character.

Comment: it seems the NumericUpDown ctrl does not accept non-numeric character

Comment: Actually what i need is an event as 'TextChanged' of textbox, but it seems that NumericUpDown does not have this event. And I think adding a new class is not appropriate for my work

Answer (score 0):

CodeProject to the rescue:

[A Derived NumericUpDown that Provides Handlers for NumericUpDown's Up and Down Button](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/DerivedNumericUpDn.aspx)

[Extended NumericUpDown control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/NumericUpDownEx.aspx)

And as a bonus, here's a wrapping NumericUpDown:

```
class WrappingNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    public override void DownButton()
    {
        if (this.Value == this.Minimum)
            this.Value = this.Maximum;
        else
            base.DownButton();
    }

    public override void UpButton()
    {
        if (this.Value == this.Maximum)
            this.Value = this.Minimum;
        else
            base.UpButton();
    }
}
```