# Restrict TextBox input upto particular value without disturbing cursor position

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox, cursor

I have a WPF application(MVVM) .I want to restrict user from entering more than specific value in a TextBox.
Suppose that value is '100' , then user shouldn't be able to enter 101 etc. I have tried following code.

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText}" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Name="SearchTextBox"  TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

CODE:

```
 private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
        {
            int searchIndex = 0;
            int count = 100;
            int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out searchIndex);

            if (textBox != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
            {
                if (searchIndex > Count)
                {
                    textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Substring(0, textBox.Text.Length - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

With this code I am able to restrict user from entering more than particular value. But problem is that when I set text of TextBox, then cursor moves to the first digit. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: better find NumericUpDown control for wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12157121/8361742) & [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45728379/8361742) . With the help of these two answers I have solved my problem. I am handling two events PreviewKeyDown & TextChanged.

code:

```
  private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
            int searchIndex = 0;
            int Count = 100;
            int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out searchIndex);
            if (textBox != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
            {
                if (searchIndex > Count)
                {
                    textBox.Text = OldValue.ToString();
                    textBox.SelectionStart = start;
                 }
             }
      }

public int OldValue = 0;
public int start = 0;


 private void SearchTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out OldValue);
        start = textBox.SelectionStart;
    }
```

I am saving oldvalue on PreviewKeyDown event and using it on TextChanged event.

Answer (score 2):

You could handle the `PreviewTextInput` event and set the `Handled` property of the `TextCompositionEventArgs` to `true` whenever the validation fails:

```
private void SearchTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        string text = textBox.Text + e.Text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            int searchIndex = 0;
            int count = 100;
            int.TryParse(text, out searchIndex);
            e.Handled = (searchIndex > count);
        }
    }
}
```

> Thanks. You answer has solved my most of the issues. But still if I delete first digit and enter another digit, then the validation fails. Suppose count is 150. I enter 150 & then delete 1 & again enter 1 then textbox will get 501 & validation will fail

Well, the you should probably stick to handling the `TextChanged` event after all. Try this:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        const int count = 100;
        int searchIndex = 0;
        int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out searchIndex);
        if (searchIndex > count)
        {
            var textChange = e.Changes.First();
            if (textChange != null && textChange.AddedLength > 0)
            {
                int caret = textBox.CaretIndex;
                int length = textBox.Text.Length;
                textBox.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
                textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Substring(0, textChange.Offset) + textBox.Text.Substring(textChange.Offset + textChange.AddedLength);
                textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
                textBox.CaretIndex = caret - Math.Abs(textBox.Text.Length - length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You answer has solved my most of the issues. But still if I delete first digit and enter another digit, then the validation fails. Suppose count is 150. I enter 150 & then delete 1 & again enter 1 then textbox will get 501 & validation will fail.

Comment: I have tried another solution and got success. I will try your solution and will accept your answer. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Code**

```
 private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
        {
            int searchIndex = 0;
            int count = 100;
            int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out searchIndex);

            if (textBox != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
            {
                if (searchIndex > count)
                {
                    textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Substring(0, textBox.Text.Length - 1);
                    textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
                    textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But problem is when we move cursor to first digit and enter value then cursor moves to last digit. And another issue is when I enter value at any place other than last digit, then first digit moves to 2nd place and last digit is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` like this:

```
if (searchIndex > Count)
{
     textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Substring(0, textBox.Text.Length - 1);
     textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length -1;
     textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```